# Inconsistent behaviour of int.to_bytes()

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I write:

```
expint = 34614  
expint = expint.to_bytes(2,'big')
```

I get a value of expint = b'\x876' instead of b'\x87\x36'(the 3 is missing and the format seems wrong). However when I tried the same with expint = 65418 I got the correct result, b'\xff\x8a'. Could this be a bug in the interpreter or other tools I'm using? I'm using Python 3.7 in Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `int.to_bytes()`, and everything to do with the `bytes` type itself.

> I get a value of expint = b'\x876' instead of b'\x87\x36'

This complaint does not make any sense, because `b'\x876'` and `b'\x87\x36'` **are the same thing**:

```
>>> b'\x87\x36'
b'\x876'
>>> b'\x87\x36' == b'\x876'
True
```

A `bytes` object's representation is *not* simply a hex dump. The grammar of byte-strings allows many other options, for historical reasons (i.e.: because in 2.x we used to pretend that they could represent text). The canonical representation (i.e. the one produced by Python when you `print` an instance) only uses `\x` style escapes as a last resort.

In ASCII, the byte with value `0x36` is mapped to the symbol `6`. (Again: we used to pretend we could represent text this way. And if we only have to deal with English plus a small selection of European languages, and can choose which European language we're dealing with at any given time, we can sort-of get away with it, too.)

Comment: `print(int.from_bytes(b'\x876',byteorder="big"))` proves this too

Comment: Also `(34614).to_bytes(2,'big').hex()` == '8736'`

Comment: Thanks Karl. You've enlightened me. The issue was that I hadn't figured out the trailing 6 in the output is to be interpreted as it's ascii value.